# SO I am trying to make a giveaway bot command but seems that I can't get the link

Tags: discord.py

So usually you do the following command: `!public #general 1 1 Discord Nitro https://discord.gg/...` but I have a hard time trying to seperate the prize and the link! Here is what I came up with:

```
@client.command()
async def public(ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel, winners: int, time: int, *prize, link):
    embed = discord.Embed(
    title = f"**Giving Away {prize}**",
    description = f"React with  to enter! \n **{winners}** winner \n \n  Must be in **{link}** to enter!", color=0xf9c900)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drop the `*` from `*prize` and just put the prize in quotes when you run your command, so:

```
!public #general 1 1 "Discord Nitro" https://discord.gg/...
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without them?

Comment: The only other option I can think of is switching the positions of your prize and link, so
`async def public(ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel, winners: int, time: int, link:str, *, prize:str):`  discord.py has no way to tell when one string begins and the next ends otherwise, as command arguments are space delimited